# Python - counting data based on field value

Tags: python, csv

Say we have a CSV file with the following data:

```
Name    Age Gender
Bob     23  Male
Ahmed   45  Male
Alice   37  Female
Ahmed   34  Male
Mariyya 10  Female
Bilal   23  Male
```

How can I do the following:

- Count the number of occurrence of each name
- Order the fields based on their frequency and show the frequency. For instance, `Ahmed` should come first with 2-times. `Male` should come first with 4-times.
- Order based on name, and show the `Gender` in the result combined with the name.

Thanks for your support.

Comment: What code have you written towards solving this? Are you using any libraries (e.g. pandas)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

csv_file = StringIO("""Name    Age Gender
Bob     23  Male
Ahmed   45  Male
Alice   37  Female
Ahmed   34  Male
Mariyya 10  Female
Bilal   23  Male""")

df = pd.read_csv(csv_file, sep="\s+",index_col=None)

df['Name'].value_counts()
```

Output:

```
Ahmed      2
Mariyya    1
Bilal      1
Bob        1
Alice      1
Name: Name, dtype: int64


df['Gender'].value_counts()
```

Output:

```
Male      4
Female    2
Name: Gender, dtype: int64

df.sort_values(by='Name')
```

Output:

```
      Name  Age  Gender
1    Ahmed   45    Male
3    Ahmed   34    Male
2    Alice   37  Female
5    Bilal   23    Male
0      Bob   23    Male
4  Mariyya   10  Female
```

Comment: Thanks for your nice answer. Just a quick question, why did you use three double quotation marks after StringIQ?

Comment: See this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10840357/string-literal-with-triple-quotes-in-function-definitions) on the triple quotes.  It handles the line breaks.